# Modal segues in xcode

Tags: xcode

When I run the application on Xcode an error appears saying "Modal segues are deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later".  When I get to the simulator everything appears very large even after I reduce the scale to 50%.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this? @NobodyNada

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two questions here.

1) Why are Modal Segues deprecated in iOS8 and should I be concerned?
and
2) Everything is big in the simulator.

Modal Segues are replaced with adaptive segues in iOS8.  The View Controller Programming Guide has information on the replacements, such as the "Show" segue and the "Show Detail" segue. The idea is that you can use one storyboard to describe an interface that works well on iPhones with small (4S, 5) screens as well as larger screens (6, 6+) and even iPads. To make efficient use of larger screens, it's now possible to have split views on iPhone in iOS8, and the new segue types let you specify that the next view should be shown in the detail area of a split view, or in the current view controller's area (aka its "context").

Traditional modal segues will continue to work, but they are not the preferred approach any longer, and as with all deprecated API, there is a possibility that a future release of the OS may remove those deprecated features. Consider revising your app to use the new approach.  There are some WWDC videos, #214 and #218 at https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ that are worth a watch if you want to get up to speed in a couple hours.

As for things being bigger in the simulator, it sounds like you're using the iPhone 6+ simulator, which is not only larger but also has 3X the pixels of a traditional iPhone non-retina.  It will be larger when you run it, so you might want to drop it down to a smaller size like 50 or 25%.  As an extra tip, those "change the size" shortcuts are Command+1, COmmand+2 and Command+3, so it's pretty easy to shuffle the size around.  Alternatively, use another simulator, like the 5S Simulator.

Comment: You would use one of the other segue types, such as Show.